# Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile: Project already has a CocoaPods dependency with name SDWebImage

Tags: kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform, kmm

I have created a demo project to integrate cocoapods into the KMM project. I have followed this [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html#add-a-dependency-on-a-pod-library-stored-locally) from the official website. At `step 3` while reimporting the project, I am receiving the following error.

`Project already has a CocoaPods dependency with name SDWebImage` , after which I am unable to even import this lib in KMM.

Can anyone please help with this?

Update: Adding `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
}

// CocoaPods requires the podspec to have a version.
 version = "1.0"

kotlin {
    android()
    ios {
        cocoapods {
            // Configure fields required by CocoaPods.
            summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
            homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"

            pod("SDWebImage")

            // You can change the name of the produced framework.
            // By default, it is the name of the Gradle project.
            frameworkName = "shared"
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

Comment: If possible, please extend the question with the build.gradle.kts file.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Have updated the build,gradle.kts. Please have a look on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you’re using cocoapods plugin you don’t need to manually declare `packForXcode` target, maybe that’s the problem. Try to remove everything after `val packForXcode`

`cocoapods` section should be inside `kotlin`, not inside `ios`

Comment: Nope. Commenting PackForXcode didnt work. Still same errors.

Comment: ok, I've found it. `cocoapods` section should be inside `kotlin`, not inside `ios`

Comment: @Phillip yep. That was an issue. But I still can't import  SDWebImage anywhere, not sure why?

Comment: this is an known issue, you can see possible solutions here: https://medium.com/icerock/enable-iosmain-sourceset-in-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-projects-91168db9ac5c

Comment: having same issue for me. @FatinWasta Any info how you fixed it. tried above solutions but didn’t work for me.

Comment: @JittyAandyan have you tried the last line "`cocoapods` section should be inside `kotlin`, not inside `ios`"? That was the problem with the author code. You may have a different one, please provide your gradle file. Or are you talking about import not being available?